# In Google Sheets, how do I make an ARRAYFORMULA be the Boolean combination of two other columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I.e., if I have:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| TRUE | TRUE |
| TRUE | FALSE |
| FALSE | TRUE |
| FALSE | FALSE |

say I want to create a column C that is  `A OR B`:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

Is this possible with `ARRAYFORMULA` or some other method which automatically creates a *RANGE* of values, without having to rely on auto-filling to increment a single column?

i.e., I'd like to do:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(OR(A:A, B:B))`

but since `OR` can take array inputs, the result of `OR(A:A, B:B)` is the single value `TRUE`, and the ARRAYFORMULA is also `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround, by treating Booleans as integers.

For OR:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A:A + B:B>0)
```

For AND:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A:A * B:B>0)
```

Would be interested to know if there's a more elegant solution, though.

Comment: *"Would be interested to know if there's a more elegant solution, though..."* There isn't a more *elegant solution*. That's the commonly accepted way to accomplish what you want. ;)